# Div moves to center when other div's disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am relatively new to jquery, and I am making a simple website. It has three boxes, all of which, when clicked, the other two will `.fadeOut('slow');`. The problem is, all of the boxes have the `<center>` tag around them. Lets say I click the box on the left. The middle and right boxes will `.fadeOut('slow')` but then the left block floats to the middle. I would be fine with this if the going to the middle was smooth, but its not.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://bit.ly/19PUmS5

Comment: add $(element).attr("style","display: block; visibility: hidden;").  This code will make the boxes appear invisible, but will act like they are still there. A more complex animation would have to be used to animate the div to the center.

Comment: @steph what might be the more complex animation? this did not work for me...

Comment: I got this code to work by making it a call back in one of your fade out functions. To make this code cleaner. You should make use of multiple selections IE     $("#two, #three").fadeOut("slow", function(){/*Called when finished fading*/})   Also you might want to try giving the same delay to all your fades, this will solve the center issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key for you is to use fadeTo() throughout your javascript.  The fadeTo() doesn't take it out of the document, so you will avoid the jump of the other squares to a new position.

Also, I streamlined your javascript a bit.  One more thing: the `<center>` tag is deprecated in html5.  Try to avoid using it.  Let me know what you think!

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="clickableContainer">
    <div class="clickable" id="one"></div>
    <div class="clickable" id="two"></div>
    <div class="clickable" id="three"></div>
    </div>
    <article class="slider" style="display:none;" id="1"><div class="back">Back</div>
    </article><article class="slider" style="display:none;" id="2"><div class="back">Back</div>
    </article><article class="slider" style="display:none;" id="3"><div class="back">Back</div>
    </article>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#one').on("click",function(){
        $("#two, #three").delay(300).fadeTo(300,0, function(){
            $('#one').delay(1000).fadeTo(300,0,function(){
                $("#one, #two, #three").css("display","none");
                $('#1').delay(1900).fadeTo('slow', 1);
            });                        
        });
    });
    $('#two').on("click",function(){
        $("#one, #three").delay(300).fadeTo(300,0, function(){
            $('#two').delay(1000).fadeTo(300,0,function(){
                $("#one, #two, #three").css("display","none");
                $('#2').delay(1900).fadeTo('slow', 1);
            });                    
        });
    });
    $('#three').on("click",function(){
        $("#one, #two").delay(300).fadeTo(300,0, function(){
            $('#three').delay(1000).fadeTo(300,0,function(){
                $("#one, #two, #three").css("display","none");
                $('#3').delay(1900).fadeTo('slow', 1); 
            });                
        });
    });
    $('article').on("click",function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(300,0,function(){
            $(this).css("display","none");
            $('#one, #two, #three').delay(800).fadeTo(300,1);
        });        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/nU8hC/3/

Comment: this worked perfectly. The only thing is now, centering the three boxes to the center of the parent.

Comment: Can you post the parent's code and accompanying css? I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function with a complete action which sets visibility to hidden:

```
$ele.fadeOut('slow', function() {
   $ele.css("display", "initial").css("visibility", "hidden");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.fadeTo` instead of `.fadeOut`. You would then need to change your code slightly, to hide and show your `<center>`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muT3g/5/)**